# Wordpress Permalinks category base prefix

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

On the WordPress permalinks page, where is the category base prefix coming from and how do I get rid of it. Where it says blog. It seems to be messing with certain slugs my theme is using.
[image: wordpress permalinks page]

Comment: Did you install your WordPress blog in a sub directory called **blog**?

Comment: No, I figured it out. it was a setting for the site. I'm currently using a Multisite installation.

Answer (score 0):

Ifigured it out. It was a setting for the main site in the Multisite admin settings. I currently have a Multisite installation.

Comment: Mark your answer as the best answer or delete your account.